# Ошибка при чтении из SQL: Scan called without calling Next

Tags: golang

```golang
rows, err2 := database.Query("select excursion_id from ex_img where id = 12")

if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println("ошбика выборки из ex_img:", err2)
}
defer rows.Close()

type Img struct {
    Id   string
}
p := Img{}

err2 = rows.Scan(&p.Id)
if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println("ошибка записи в структуру: ", err2)
}
```

Ошибка: `Scan called without calling Next`.

Comment: Точно не могу говорить но скорее всего ваш ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845619/how-to-call-the-scan-variadic-function-in-golang-using-reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, прочитайте [документацию](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/)! Там же специально для вас пример того, как использовать эти API:

```golang
rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)

// …

names := make([]string, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    var name string
    if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    names = append(names, name)
}

if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Printf("%s are %d years old", strings.Join(names, ", "), age)
```

Не говоря уже о [прямом упоминании](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) необходимости вызвать `Next`:

> Every call to Scan, even the first one, must be preceded by a call to Next.